# How to create a REST URL using json-server and use it in automation in vRO

Tags: automation, vmware, javascript-automation

I have added http://localhost:3000 as a part of "Add a REST host" workflow in vRO and this is successful but when I try to run "Invoke a REST host" it fails giving the error "cannot execute the request; connection refused".

I am running json-server on my localhost port 3000. And the URL I want to connect is http://localhost:3000/hosts.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a REST host in vRO means that this host is used to connect to by vRO.
Assuming your vRO is an appliance and your "localhost" is your system (not the appliance), you have to add the REST host in vRO with the URL `http://ipfromyouthost:port` to get vRO connected to your host at port 3000.
Otherwise (like in your question) vRO tries to connect to itself (localhost) on port 3000 which is not open per default.